# woocommerce products white backgrounds have noise only on Win8

Tags: css, woocommerce, windows-8.1

I'm having this issue on a Win 8.1 computer on all browsers and I can't figure out a solution. I tried everything else (linux, android, win7 on Virtual Box, and ipad), but the problem isn't there. You can see the issue at this address

www.amicamako.com/shop

All white backgrounds have a noise, like blueish vertical lines not so easy to see but definitely there. Only on this win 8.1 laptop, on any browser.

Really can't figure this out.. any help is really appreciated

Comment: how is this related to SO?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using WooCommerce on Wordpress.

This is the problem with the default library Wordpress uses to resize images: GD Library. I change the library to ImageMagick and the white background noise is solved.

This is the plug-in page:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/imagemagick-engine/

Note that you need to have ImageMagick installed in your system as well. If you're not sure you can Google: install ImageMagick PHP or Wordpress

Comment: thank you for your answers, I think I'll have a try, I found out this only happens on a few machines and noise can be seen only by looking to the screen from a side, so I decided to live with it for now, but I'll try imagemagick out, thanks again!